# cant use eevee alpha clip and blend mode together

Tags: eevee-render-engine

can anyone help me fix this?

am making a spaceship camouflage shader in eevee and in order to make that i have to set the blend mode to alpha blend on the material section but the thing is there is a a lot of PNG(transparent) textures on top of the spaceship texture so whatever i set it to alpha blend instead of alpha clip those png textures  disappear so how can i make both work at the same time?
[image]